# Documentation - Too many narrow topics? One topic per method?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

An example is the [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/google-apps-script/topics).

I see almost one topic per method for the `DriveApp` service. It's cluttered, and seems less likely to help newbies than Google's actual documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app). I don't want to just go through and downvote them all, as I think that would be rude, and far too assertive of my personal opinion, but I believe it's becoming too narrow.

There is not much room for other examples inside the topics, as they are very narrow.

What are your thoughts? If this is too narrow, how would you go about preventing such clutter?

Comment: There needs to be some guidelines for how to structure the documentation.  Traditional documentation may use the structure of the language to structure the documentation.  The focus and the goal should be for information to be easily found in a search.  It would be interesting to study how people with no knowledge of the language try to find what they are looking for.  If they have no knowledge of the language, then they don't know the method or class names.  So that won't help a new user.  So, that may be an argument against titles as class and method names. Both pros and cons to evaluate.

Comment: As far as "clutter", it would be good to get feedback to determine what the majority of people find as easy to understand structure, and what they see as clutter.  Maybe a poll with some examples could be used to determine what the consensus is.  One of my biggest frustrations with documentation has always been that the documentation is too narrow, has no broader context, and often has no example of how to connect critical parts of the language.  There are however, some methods, that really don't have many alternative uses.  There is also a possible issue of too many examples.  That's clutter.

Answer (score 8):

I believe it's the case that Documentation was originally designed to be *exactly* like you describe - one topic per method.

- Examples showcase what you can use this method for;
- Parameters documents the parameters of a single method - documenting parameters for multiple methods in one table doesn't work so well;
- Syntax documents the various possible method signatures (with things like C# in mind, where one method can have multiple call signatures);
- Remarks is free-form, but seems to have been intended as comments on this one method.

One topic per method isn't how Documentation is getting used in reality, for most tags. Instead, topics are being used as broader scoped documents about a concept, rather than a method.

Whether that's a good thing or not is up for debate.

Personally, I would have liked to see topics being used for single methods, and the inclusion of a different type of document that could be used for the broader concepts.

As for this particular tag, it's probably best to let the documentation grow by itself and see what direction it takes. Once its format is broadly determined, it's easier to see where that format has its shortcomings, and do something to fix those, rather than trying to foresee potential issues.

Comment: I think *see what direction it takes* is part of the problem. There is no guidance apparently, and frustration from expectations. Much time is spent crafting Examples when a large part of the Community might suggest it shouldn't happen in the first place.

Comment: *"Instead, topics are being used as broader scoped documents about a concept, rather than a method"* - Which is good. Documents about syntax can be found anywhere. Real-life examples are what is usually missing. Maybe it should be possible to write a real-life example and link it to the topics for the various core methods that are used in it... Consider this a feature-request for Documents 0.2. ;-)